# Django- How to display 1000 models 10 at a time?

Tags: python, django

I have a view where I want a user to be able to scroll down a small div of 1000+ django objects, having no more than 10 showing at once.  Also a search function

What would the best option be?

Should I store the objects in the browser and retrieve them?
Should I just rewrite the view to display 10 at a time?
Is there an elegant js solution?

Thanks guys.

Comment: How does the view currently look? Thanks.

Comment: It is just doing an MyObject.objects.all() then a for loop in the template to display the objects.

Answer (score 2):

Django has build in [Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/). There are several project that offer a AJAX solution on top of that, one is i.e. [django-endless-pagination](https://github.com/frankban/django-endless-pagination).

Another solution could be something like [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). There is also a project to help integrating it with Django called [django-datatables-view](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-datatables-view/1.8)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I will definitely look into these options!

Answer (score 1):

There is almost no cases when you can load everything onto client side to make pagination. For example, you can use firebase or rarely reload page.

So, for your case, you should implement ajax view to get needed portion of data. Like Martin said, Django has sexy and easy to use class Paginator, which will help you to deal with everything!

Your view will be like:

```
@ajax_request
def my_view_ajax(req):
    pages = Paginator(Doc.objects.all(), 10)
    page = pages.page(int(request.GET.get('page', 1)))
    return {
        'total_pages': p.num_pages,
        'data': [{
            'id': doc.id,
            'title': doc.title,
            'excerpt': doc.excerpt,
        } for doc in page.object_list]
    }
```

So, you have total pages and data to display.